# What is the best approach to implement HATEOS REST API to return an aggregate Order object?

Tags: api, rest, asp.net-core, restful-url

I'm using .net core and having two microservices named `Customer_Api` and `Order_Api`. I'm trying to stick to RESTful best practices and to also apply HATEOS. I have an `Order` model class that looks like this:

```
    public class Order : BaseEntity
    {
        public string TransactionId { get; set; }

        public decimal Total { get; set; }

        public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

        public Guid DeliveryAddressId { get; set; }

        public virtual OrderDeliveryAddress DeliveryAddress { get; set; }

        public ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
    }
```

**Assumption:**

1. let's assume this is a medium-size e-commerce system with loads of requests coming to our microservices
2. and our order class represents correct and enough structure

**Question:**

Now, I'm writing a `GET` API to return a single `order`. If I want to stick to the HATEOS, does that mean the API response should not contain the customer object such as the customer's name, and instead, just return the customer id with a URL link that the client can use to get a customer from the customer microservice? And the same practice for Order Lines and also the delivery address, or basically, for *any other resource* that could come into our `Order` object, we should return the relative GET URL rather than the object itself to stick to the HATEOS?

I would say a HATEO response for the order object should look like this in `JSON`:

```
{
     "transactionId": "blabla",
     "customerId": "blabla",
     "customerUrl": "https://localhost:443/customer/blabla",
     "orderLines": [ { "id": "bla", "orderUrl": "https://localhost:442/order/bla" } ],
     ....
}
```

Does this make sense? Or is this over-kill? or maybe not efficient? Highly appreciate it if someone could confirm my thoughts or clarify this for me.

Comment: Heuristic: think about how you would do it on the web with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a method to create HEATOS links. that method `transactionId` `customerId` `orderLines` and build and append `customerUrl` in result response.

for exapmle

```
  //exaple reository
    public order GetOrderRepository()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        return new order()
        {
            orderId = r.Next(0, 99999)
        };
    }
    //exaple endpoint
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<order> getOrder()
    {
        var order = GetOrderRepository();
        return Ok(GetOrderWithHeatos(order));
    }
    //our HEATOS builder
    public order GetOrderWithHeatos(order order)
    {
        order.orderUrl = new Uri($"AbsloutePath/{order.orderId}").ToString();
        return order;
    }
```